# Ubuntu VPS running VPN server not forwarding packets

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, vps, ipsec

I've asked a related question here - [Can't route back down ipsec tunnel from VPS](https://serverfault.com/questions/648540/cant-route-back-down-ipsec-tunnel-from-vps?noredirect=1#comment785782_648540) - but I've answered that and moved on a bit.

The end goal of what I'm trying to achieve is this:

We have a bunch of 4G routers that, as is standard for the UK, sit behind a couple of layers of carrier grade NAT and therefore are not publicly addressable. We have a need to be able to talk back to these routers from a server on AWS. My idea to achieve this was to set up a VPS that did have a static IP address and establish a VPN from the 4G router to the VPS. We can then communicate with the 4G router via the public IP on the VPS that would be set to forward traffic back down the VPN tunnel.

Where I'm at:

I've set up a VPS on Digital Ocean and set up a libreSwan IPSec VPN using this script - https://github.com/philplckthun/setup-simple-ipsec-l2tp-vpn - and got the VPN successfully established from the router to the VPS. I can ping from the VPS to the router and to other devices connected to the router (which was my initial problem). The router is set to use the VPN tunnel as the default route and when I ping the VPS from the router I can see packets arriving from the router's local address (same as for devices connected to the router) but now I have a problem where if I ping an internet address (e.g. 8.8.8.8) from the router, I can see the packets hitting the VPS but they are not getting forwarded out to the Internet (proven by pinging another machine on the internet and watching TCPdump). I have set up forwarding in /etc/sysctl.conf (`net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`) and enabled MASQUERADE in iptables (`-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`). I've also tried several other iptables rules I've found around the web but nothing has helped.

Network diagram:

```
laptop (used for testing) --- 4G router --- Internet/VPN tunnel --- DO VPS
192.168.0.159                192.168.0.1                           public IP
```

If I ping 8.8.8.8 from the laptop, this is what TCPdump on the VPS sees:

```
14:24:58.713759 IP 192.168.0.159 > google-public-dns-a.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 714, length 40
```

but the laptop doesn't get a reply and as I said, I've confirmed the packets aren't getting any further.

VPS' routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         178.62.64.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
178.62.64.0     *               255.255.192.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
```

What am I doing wrong (apart from getting up and coming to work)?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to assign a virtual IP address to eth0.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question; in the ipsec.conf on the server we had `left=<server's subnet>`. Changing this to `left=0.0.0.0/0` got the forwarding working as expected.